Telethon: How to send request for joining channel?
There is a (kind of) new feature in Telegram. When you click invite link, you send a request to join and admin must approve it before you can view the channel.
I cannot find how can I send such request from telethon. Is it possible?

Telethon can do everything official clients can do (except for sign up), so yes. I don't know how, but you can enable debugmode in the official Telegram Desktop client. Then you can make the request and read the logs to find out which one it is. (Note that I've linked the v2 documentation, which is a version that has not yet been released and may still change.)

Thanks, that is actually an answer I looked for. I ended up using ImportChatInviteRequest, maybe I tried it and though it doesn't work because it raises an exception (telegram api sometimes is so strange, it raises an exception when it is success).
you can post it as answer, I will accept it

I don't have the code at hand so I'm more likely to make mistakes, but if you do, you can answer your own question and approve it, too.
